# Questions about learning

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

Can I ask questions about how and where to learn a specific subject? In my case that would be something like:

> What is the minimum knowledge necessary to start learning about kalman filtering? What are good books on the subject?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think questions about the minimum requirements for learning about a subject are a good fit for this site, as long as the question also gives some background on why one is interested in the subject (to give people an idea of what level one will need to learn the subject on).

This is the sort of question that can otherwise be very hard to find an answer for.

Answer (score 7):

I think if you'll put a little about what you already know and/or what your background is, this is a [reference-request](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reference-request) and there are plenty...